# Difference between Basic and Dynamic Disk Types

Tags: windows-10

In order to install dual boot Ubuntu, I needed more memory in local disk C, which is why I created a new disk from D drive, transfer all th the new disk and deleted data from D. Just to create a contiguous memory block so I can extend the C drive. When I created new drive it changed all the drive types from ''Basic" to "Dynamic". I googled it but couldn't really understand the difference. Would it affect the working of PC in any way? If it does, what is the easiest way to change it back to basic type.

Thank you!

Comment: [What Are Basic and Dynamic Disks – Features, Differences, Conversion](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/what-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks.html) answers all of your questions.

Comment: [Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk)

Comment: Note there are several commercial programs that will convert without the need to have a backup (although this is recommended) and restoring data from backup.

Answer (score 0):

The Disk Management utility in Windows uses the terminology Basic and Dynamic to refer to the use of certain metadata on the disk used for what it calls "dynamic volumes" This can refer to two things. One is Microsofts way of expanding the MBR partition scheme to supporting more than 4 partitions by adding what is called the extended partition as the forth partition and it contains metadata about the rest of the partitions. The other is for disks with spanning volumes like stripping (RAID 0) or mirroring (RAID 1) etc. Chances are you're concerned with the first bit.

Generally speaking operating systems can not be booted off a "dynamic" partition including Windows and Linux. Meaning a partition that is described in the extended partition or any partition except the first three since the extended partition takes up one of the MBR partitions and uses it to describe the "extended" ones.

Linux can mount extended partitions but has limited support for them in certain tools. Microsofts tools don't let you convert dynamic back to basic but there are third party tools that do so. Generally though if Microsoft doesn't trust itself to do the conversation I'd make sure to do a data backup.

To avoid all that mess in the future however you can use GPT partitioning scheme.

Comment: Dynamic partitions in Windows LDM are _not_ the same thing as extended/logical partitions in MBR. Linux supports both, but they use quite different metadata formats. (And OSes could technically boot from either, it's just more troublesome.)

Comment: @grawity I understand this. Doesn't change the fact both types are labeled "dynamic" In that case referring to dynamic disks. Blame microsoft for being confusing here.

Comment: But they're not. Not sure where you got that 'fact' from, but I've had several Windows systems with extended & logical MBR partitions, and none of them refer to those as a 'dynamic volume' or 'dynamic disk'.